# Can a Parameterized method be called in a TestNG XML Suite?

Tags: java, xml, selenium-webdriver, testng, suite

I have a parameterized method(`readConfig_1(String path)`) in a class which I need to run before the tests in a TestNG Suite. Is there a way that I can call this method and define the parameter for the same in the TestNG.xml file?

Here's the Parameterized Method, I have written which actually needs a path to where the XML file is stored.

```
public static void readConfig_1(String configXmlPath) 
{

            browser = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, "config",
                    "browser");
             env = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, "config", "env");
             release = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, "config", "release");
            serverName = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env,
                    "serverName");
             host = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "host");
            userName = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "userName");
            passWord = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "passWord");
            portNumber = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env,
                    "portNumber");
            schema = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "schema");
            url = CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "url");
            screenShotForPass=CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "SCreenShotForPass");

            screenShotForFail=CoreLib.fGetNodeText(configXmlPath, env, "SCreenShotForFail");


            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("****************************************************");
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("           Configuration Details                    ");
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("****************************************************");

            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("Browser ::" + browser);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("env ::" + env);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("serverName ::" + serverName);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("host ::" + host);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("userName ::" + userName);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("passWord ::" + passWord);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("portNumber ::" + portNumber);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("schema ::" + schema);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("url::" + url);
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("ScreenSnapShotForPass::"+screenShotForPass );
            CoreLib.LOGGER.info("ScreenSnapShotForFail::"+screenShotForFail );

        }
```

In this TestNG Suite seen below, I need to call the above method passing a parameter to it before it can go ahead and run the tests written in the other classes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Smoke Suite" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.healthcare.reports.MyListener"></listener>
    </listeners>



    <test name="XYZ Tests">
        <classes>

            <class name="com.healthcare.utility.Config">
                <methods>
                    <include name="readConfig_1"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>

            <class name="com.healthcare.businessLib.xyz.AddUserTests" />

        </classes>

    </test>


</suite>
```

By this I intend to restrict a TestNG Suite to read a particular Config.XML file which will have it's own values such as Env, URL, browser etc., set before the tests can be executed. Is there a way I can achieve this?

---

----**Added 11/24/2017**-----

---- **I thought adding the readConfig_1 to a @BeforeClass annotation would resolve the problem. But there's more to it**-----

My Listener Class has `**@onStart**` annotation which needs the config file to be run on the start of the Suite. As you see below my Listener Class has the variables release_1 coming from Config file.

```
 public class MyListener implements ITestListener, ISuiteListener {

        // This belongs to ISuiteListener and will execute before the Suite start

        ReportLib report=new ReportLib();

        @Override
        public void onStart(ISuite arg0) {

            Config.readConfig_1(configXlsPath);
            ExportTestResults export = new ExportTestResults();
            export.exportExcelHeader(Config.release_1);
            CoreLib.fCreateLogger(Config.release_1);

        }
```

But if I put it in @BeforeClass in a TestClass these variables(**Config.release_1**) are returning null as they would be running before the test class. So I need the readconfig_1 to run **before or with the Listener class** and unable to add a parameter to the `onStart(ISuite arg0)`.

Tried a few things by :

1. Running the `readConfig_1()` in the TestNG.XML as the first method even before the listener class could be called.
2. putting a `@BeforeClass` annotation in the Listener class with `readConfig_1()` method parameterized in it- hoping that the readConfig would be called before the onStart() is executed.

   ```
   public class MyListener2 implements ITestListener, ISuiteListener {

       ReportLib report=new ReportLib();

       @BeforeClass
       @Parameters("configXlsPath")
       public void beforeSuite(String configXlsPath)
       {
           Config.readConfig_1(configXlsPath);
           System.out.println("In Before Class(Listener_2)"+ Config.release_1);
       }


       @Override
       public void onStart(ISuite arg0) {

           ExportTestResults export = new ExportTestResults();
           System.out.println("In onStart(Listener_2)"+ Config.release_1);
           export.exportExcelHeader(Config.release_1);
           CoreLib.fCreateLogger(Config.release_1);

       }
   ```

   }

But none worked.
**Is there a way around this now?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can take some help from [here](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/parameterization-in-testng)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @JeffC - Sure, I will do that in some time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SK Should you be including a config method as a test? Will it not mess up the report? Try making it a before method.

Comment: @SK I pushed an answer for your question.  Please implement that and let me know if it is best fit or not for your need.

Comment: @Grasshopper yeah.. This is how I was trying to implement it. But with all the suggestions, I think I will put in a BeforeClass Method. Thanks.

Comment: @AliAzam All the answers below works but I think putting it in a BeforeClass works best for my case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SK I also used it in BeforeClass method and it works fine here. But I saw your question that you would like to run on Before Test method. So I am updating this to work on precisely

Comment: @AliAzam Grasshopper:  I tried putting it in BeforeClass and I realized that I am creating an excel header and also Logger which needs the 'env' variable from the Cofig file and running the readConfig method in Testclass does mess up my report. So I need some suggestion around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Firstly, add `@Parameters("configXmlPath")` annotation to your test class. `configXmlPath` parameter must also be defined in `testng.xml` file like `<parameter name = "configXmlPath" value="Whateverthevalueis"/>` this. Here is an example.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class YourTest {
   @Test
   @Parameters("configXmlPath")
   public void test1(String configXmlPath) {
      System.out.println("Parameterized value is : " + configXmlPath);
   }
}
```

Then, in your testng.xml define parameter like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name = "Suite1">
   <test name = "test1">

      <parameter name = "configXmlPath" value="Whateverthevalueis"/> 

     <classes>
         <class name = "YourTest" />
      </classes>

    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: I have checked with all the solutions and putting it in BeforeClass works best. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I apologize for unmarking this as a solution to my problem. But there's more to the problem itself. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In your java method , use @BeforeClass and @Parameters annotation ,

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"configXlsPath"})
public static void readConfig_1(@Optional("addaDefaultPathValue") String configXlsPath)
```

In your xml , add a parameter tag after tests tag.

```
<test name="Purchaser Tests">
 <parameter name="configXlsPath" value="target/path/to/xmlFile">
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use BeforeSuite or BeforeTest

Comment: Have worked with BeforeSuite , null parameters are passed to the class methods. BeforeTest will reset the value after  execution of each @Test annotated method. As per convention, configuration file should be loaded once . so BeforeClass is the right candidate annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your Parameterized Method under `@BeforeClass` annotations and should be inside the test class or inherited from other class. 
I was also dealing with the same issue and resolved this in the below ways:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AddUserTests {

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters("configXmlPath")
    public void readConfig_1(String configXmlPath){
      System.out.println("File path : "+ configXmlPath);

       /*
            You can use the configXmlPath value to 
            your code that goes here
       */      
    }

    @Test
    public void test_1(){
        //Test Code 
    }

    @Test
    public void test_2(){
        //Test Code     
    }       
}
```

You need to define and set your parameter value in the xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Smoke Suite" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.healthcare.reports.MyListener"></listener>
    </listeners>

    <test name="XYZ Tests">
      <parameter name="configXmlPath" value="USE_ABSOLUTE_PATH_HERE"/> 
        <classes>
            <class name="com.healthcare.businessLib.xyz.AddUserTests" />
        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

Please use the absolute path [i.e,`C://Config.XML`] of the config file instead of `USE_ABSOLUTE_PATH_HERE`